# Is our fulfilled user commitments normal?

Tags: discussion

I was just looking on Area 51 at our site stats to see how far we had gone towards graduating from beta and in particular noticed this:

> committed users
>
> 216 users committed
>
> 71.8% signed up for beta
>
> 17.6% fulfilled commitment

I admit I don't use this site at much as I had planned to (though I think my overall SE usage has dropped over the past year as well), but the 17.6% fulfilling commitment seems rather low.

1) Is that percentage normal among sites that eventually graduated from beta?  If not, is that a bad sign?

2) How do I know if I'm one of the 17.6% or the 82.4%?  I thought I fulfilled the commitment, but now I'm not sure I remembered correctly.

Comment: Area 51 isn't indicative of progress towards graduation. Graduation criteria have since changed drastically, and A51 stats should be taken with a grain of salt.

Comment: @Emrakul Ah, so how is graduation decided then?

Comment: The body of the current discussion is [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites), and hasn't changed too much since then. Most of the metrics are non-numeric.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### 1) Is that percentage normal among sites that eventually graduated from beta? If not, is that a bad sign?

Looking at some of the other Stack Exchange sites on Area51, our "fulfilled commitment" percentage seems "normal". (Most of the other sites that were created around the same time we were have around a 15-20% follow through rate). But I don't think it's an important question. The goal of the Area51  process is to create a successful site that can thrive on its own. Looking at our site, it seems like we're doing OK.

#### 2) How do I know if I'm one of the 17.6% or the 82.4%? I thought I fulfilled the commitment, but now I'm not sure I remembered correctly.

[image: Screenshot of Kimball's Area51 profile, showing that Kimball fulfilled their commitment.]

Looks like you fulfilled the Area51 commitment.

Comment: Thanks, though now I am more troubled about modern society than before to know that perhaps only 15-20% of people follow through on their word.  And I took SE users to be on the more responsible side too...

Comment: I'm not sure it's much of a reliable statement about the state of modern society or people's "responsibility". There's various factors involved here.

Comment: @CahirMawrDyffrynæpCeallach That statement was somewhat tongue-in-cheek.